# Android Async Task Freezes UI Completely

Tags: android, user-interface, asynchronous, android-asynctask

I have an Async task that loads information from the server and displays data on the UI. Suddenly the async task downloads the data and formats the JSON data fine but it would freeze the UI completely.

Here is the base download class

```
public class GetRawData {

private static String LOG_TAG = GetRawData.class.getSimpleName();
private String mRawURL;
private List<NameValuePair> mRawParams = null;
private String mRawData;
private DownloadStatus mDownloadStatus;

public GetRawData(String mRawURL) {
    this.mRawURL = mRawURL;
    this.mRawParams = null;
    this.mDownloadStatus = DownloadStatus.IDLE;
}

public String getRawData() {
    return mRawData;
}

public void setRawURL(String mRawURL) {
    this.mRawURL = mRawURL;
}

public List<NameValuePair> getRawParams() {
    return mRawParams;
}

public void setRawParams(List<NameValuePair> mParams) {
    this.mRawParams = mParams;
}

public DownloadStatus getDownloadStatus() {
    return mDownloadStatus;
}

public void reset() {
    this.mRawURL = null;
    this.mRawData = null;
    this.mDownloadStatus = DownloadStatus.IDLE;
}

public void execute() {
    this.mDownloadStatus = DownloadStatus.PROCESSING;
    DownloadRawData mDownloadRawData = new DownloadRawData();
    mDownloadRawData.execute(mRawURL);
}

public class DownloadRawData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // Create URL and Reader instances.
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        //If no parameter has been provided, return null.
        if (params == null)
            return null;

        try {
            // Get URL entered by the user.
            URL mURL = new URL(params[0]);

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) mURL.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");

            //urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Host", "android.schoolportal.gr");
            urlConnection.connect();

            // validate and add parameters if available.
            if (mRawParams != null && mRawParams.size()>0){
                JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();

                for (NameValuePair pair : mRawParams) {
                    jsonParam.put(pair.getName().toString(), pair.getValue().toString());
                }

                String jsonparams = jsonParam.toString();

                // Send POST output.
                DataOutputStream printout;
                printout = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
                printout.writeBytes(jsonparams);
                printout.flush();
                printout.close();
            }

            int HttpResult =urlConnection.getResponseCode();

            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            if(HttpResult ==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                if (inputStream == null) {
                    return null;
                }
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line + "\n");
                }
                System.out.println(""+buffer.toString());

            }else{

                InputStream errorStream = urlConnection.getErrorStream();
                if (errorStream == null) {
                    return null;
                }
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(errorStream));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line + "\n");
                }
                System.out.println(urlConnection.getResponseMessage());
            }


            return buffer.toString();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("IOException", e.toString());
            return null;
        } catch (JSONException j) {
            Log.d("JSONException", j.toString());
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d("IOException", "unable to close the reader");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        mRawData = result;
        //Log.d("onPostExecute", result);

        if (mRawData == null) {
            if (mRawURL == null) {
                mDownloadStatus = DownloadStatus.NOT_INITIALIZED;
            } else {
                mDownloadStatus = DownloadStatus.FAILED_OR_EMPTY;
            }
        } else {
            mDownloadStatus = DownloadStatus.PROCESSED;
        }
    }

    private String getQuery(List<NameValuePair> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;

        for (NameValuePair pair : params) {
            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
                result.append("&");

            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getName(), "UTF-8"));
            result.append("=");
            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
        }

        return result.toString();
    }
}

}
enum DownloadStatus {
IDLE,
PROCESSING,
NOT_INITIALIZED,
FAILED_OR_EMPTY,
PROCESSED
}
```

Here is the specific data formatting class the extends above class

```
public class GetJobCardJsonData extends GetRawData {
private static String LOG_TAG = GetAuthenticationJsonData.class.getSimpleName();
private static String JOBCARD_SERVICE_URL = "http://www.appservice.com/appservice/jobcardinfoservice.asmx/GetJobCardInfo";
private List<JobCard> mJobCardList;
private CarcalDownloadListener mListener;

public GetJobCardJsonData(String CurrentDate, int DealershipID) {
    super(null);

    List<NameValuePair> mParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    mParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("JobCardDate", CurrentDate));
    mParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("DealershipID", String.valueOf(DealershipID)));
    this.setRawParams(mParams);
}

public List<JobCard> getJobCardList() {
    return mJobCardList;
}

public void getjobcards() {
    super.setRawURL(JOBCARD_SERVICE_URL);
    DownloadJobCardJsonData mDownloadJobCardJsonData = new DownloadJobCardJsonData();
    mDownloadJobCardJsonData.execute(JOBCARD_SERVICE_URL);
}

public void setOnCarcalDownloadListener(CarcalDownloadListener onCarcalDownloadListener) {
    this.mListener = onCarcalDownloadListener;
}

private void processResult() {
    if (getDownloadStatus() != DownloadStatus.PROCESSED) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error Downloading the raw file.");
        return;
    }

    if (mJobCardList == null){
        mJobCardList = new ArrayList<JobCard>();
    }

    final String JOBCARD_JOBCARDID = "JobCardID";
    final String JOBCARD_GETSTOCKNUMBER_WITH_DELIVERYTIME = "StockNumberWithDeliveryTime";
    final String JOBCARD_CUSTOMERNAME = "CustomerName";
    final String JOBCARD_MODELNUMBER = "ModelNumber";
    final String JOBCARD_COLOR = "Color";
    final String JOBCARD_SALEEXECUTIVE = "SaleExecutive";
    final String JOBCARD_ORDERSTATUS = "OrderStatus";
    final String JOBCARD_SHOWROOMSTATUS = "ShowRoomStatus";

    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(getRawData());

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jobcarditem = jsonArray.optJSONObject(i);

            Long JOBCARDID = jobcarditem.getLong(JOBCARD_JOBCARDID);
            String STOCKWITHDELIVERY = jobcarditem.getString(JOBCARD_GETSTOCKNUMBER_WITH_DELIVERYTIME);
            String CUSTOMERNAME = jobcarditem.getString(JOBCARD_CUSTOMERNAME);
            String MODELNUMBER = jobcarditem.getString(JOBCARD_MODELNUMBER);
            String COLOR = jobcarditem.getString(JOBCARD_COLOR);
            String SALEEXECUTIVE = jobcarditem.getString(JOBCARD_SALEEXECUTIVE);
            int ORDERSTATUS = jobcarditem.getInt(JOBCARD_ORDERSTATUS);
            int SHOWROOMSTATUS = jobcarditem.getInt(JOBCARD_SHOWROOMSTATUS);

            JobCard mJobCard = new JobCard(JOBCARDID, STOCKWITHDELIVERY, CUSTOMERNAME, MODELNUMBER, COLOR, SALEEXECUTIVE, ORDERSTATUS, SHOWROOMSTATUS);
            mJobCardList.add(mJobCard);
        }

    } catch (JSONException jsone) {
        jsone.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing json data.");
    }

}

public class DownloadJobCardJsonData extends DownloadRawData {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        return super.doInBackground(params[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        processResult();
        mListener.OnDownloadCompleted();
    }
}

}
```

Here is the code that is called on the activity

```
private JobCardRecyclerViewAdapter mJobCardRecyclerViewAdapter;
private GetJobCardJsonData mGetJobCardJsonData;
SessionManager session;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_job_card_calender);
    activateToolbarWithHomeEnabled();

    String formattedDate="";
    if (session.getCurrentDate() == ""){
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
        currentDateTextView.setText(formattedDate);
    }else {
        formattedDate = session.getCurrentDate();
        currentDateTextView.setText(formattedDate);
    }

    // Fetch data for current date.
        mGetJobCardJsonData = new GetJobCardJsonData(formattedDate, session.getDealershipID());
        mGetJobCardJsonData.getjobcards();
        mGetJobCardJsonData.setOnCarcalDownloadListener(new CarcalDownloadListener() {
            @Override
            public void OnDownloadCompleted() {
                List<JobCard> mJobCards = mGetJobCardJsonData.getJobCardList();
                mJobCardRecyclerViewAdapter = new JobCardRecyclerViewAdapter(mJobCards, JobCardCalenderActivity.this);
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mJobCardRecyclerViewAdapter);
            }
        });

}
```

Can anyone help on what i am doing wrong that is freezing the UI. It was working fine before and has started to freeze the UI suddenly.

Comment: Use Traceview, and perhaps `StrictMode`, to determine where you are spending your time on the main application thread.

Comment: thanks for your prompt response, I am naive to android development. could you provide an example of how we can use StrictMode to trace UI thread?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue, the problem was not with Async task but with the layout. I accidently wrapped the recycler view with scroll view. which was causing the UI to freeze. Looks weird that a scroll view caused the whole UI thread to freeze. but here is my solution

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <view
        android:id="@+id/jobCardRecyclerView"
        class="android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/jobCardHeader"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"></view>

</ScrollView>
```

Changed it to

```
<view
        android:id="@+id/jobCardRecyclerView"
        class="android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/jobCardHeader"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"></view>
```

hope it will be helpful for others facing same problem.